# How to use Proc defined by scope of association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I am writing a gem for automatic scope generation (see [AssociationScope](https://github.com/datae95/association_scope)).
I already did much work and currently I am working on scoped associations.
[Rails Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-belongs-to) mentions how to write scoped associations, but not how to generally use them.

When I have the example from Rails Guide

```rb
class Book < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, -> { where active: true }
end
```

I can use `Book.reflections["author"]` to see all relevant information for that association. With `Book.reflections["author"].scope` I get

```rb
#<Proc:0x0000560511e55d28 /home/datae/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/activerecord-6.1.3.1/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:54>
```

I want to automatically generated a scope based on this association.
How can I use this `Proc`?

**Steps to recreate application:**

```
rails g model Book author:references
rails g model Author active:boolean
rails db:migrate
```

replace the generated `Book` class with the above code from Rails Guide.

Comment: `belongs_to` is basically a macro that [creates 6 other methods](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference). When you ask how to use that proc then I wonder which method created do you want to use and how do you want to use it?

Comment: Yes, but I don't need these methods. I want to automatically generated a scope based on this association. So when the association itself has a scope, which is, for the above example, stored in `Book.reflections["author"].scope`, I have to use it.